# При конструировании списка из enum элемент с value 0 помечается selected

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net, asp.net-core

Я хочу сделать выпадающий список с элементами из перечисления

```
NotSelected = -1,
Other = 0,
Cafe = 1,
Shop = 2,
...
```

На стороне сервера я генерирую список следующим образом

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetEnumSelectListIntValues<TEnum>(this IHtmlHelper @this) where TEnum : struct
{
    var res = @this.GetEnumSelectList<TEnum>().OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Value));
    if (res.Any()) {
            res.First().Disabled = true;
            res.First().Selected = true;
            foreach (var e in res.Skip(1))
            {
                e.Selected = false;
            }
    }
    return res;
}
```

То есть явно указываю, что элемент со значением -1 должен быть выделен.
Далее я с помощью этой функции создаю список элементов перечисления для таг хелпера

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="Category" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectListIntValues<PurchaseCategory>()">
        </select>
```

Но на клиенте я вижу, что элемент Other (со значением 0) в списке помечен как selected, вместо ожидаемого мной NotSelected (со значением -1).

```
<select class="form-control valid" data-val="true" data-val-range="Укажите категорию" data-val-range-max="2147483647" data-val-range-min="0" data-val-required="The Category field is required." id="Category" name="Category" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="Category-error">
<option value="-1">Выберите категорию</option>
<option selected="selected" value="0">Другое</option>
<option value="1">Кафе и рестораны</option>
</select>
```

Как мне побороть эту напасть и почему так происходит?

P.S. Сделать NotSelected = 0 я не могу по определенным причинам

Comment: 2. disabled и selected не должно встречаться одновременно в option (в select можно в option нельзя)

Comment: Если я убираю disabled, то ничего не меняется, к сожалению. Поведение остается точно таким же, атрибут selected проставляется элементу со значением 0

Comment: Нужно установить selected для всего списка (1).  `foreach (var e in res){
                e.Selected =  int.Parse(e.Value) == sel_value;
            }` так например

Comment: Вижу уже - вам мой совет не поможет. А к самому списку у вас доступ есть? Вы можете задать что-то вроде `listBox1.SelectedValue = "-1";`?

Comment: Это asp.net, я на вход ему подаю список с теми флагами, что мне нужны, однако после внутренней обработки при выдаче сформированного html клиенту, он по какой-то причине устанавливает атрибуты по-своему. Соответственно доступа к самому списку у меня нет.